# Getting rid of dashes in a file with sed

Tags: sed

I'd like to use the sed command to get rid of some dashes in a string (inside a file), i.e., the file has a line that says:

```
TEXT=abcdef-lalala-someText-yahoo
```

After the sed execution, that line should look like:

```
TEXT=abcdeflalalasomeTextyahoo
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: -1 for not properly describing what you were looking for.

Comment: Wilmer *has* quite reasonably phrased his question. Taken literally and considering a programmer's idiom, it is pretty clear what he wants.       
He speaks of  *"a"* string and *"that"* line, but does not mention *any* or *all* lines. Typically "foo", "abcdef", "lalala" mean variable data; therefore I can assume that "TEXT=" and "yahoo" are constants (unless he says otherwise). I was originally ambivalent about "yahoo", but since the mark-downs, I've re-focused on the question and I should adjust my answer, even though Wilmer was gracious enough to not complain about my oversight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your further comment to *Nifle's* answer, perhaps this is more like what you are looking for.  It will only acts on lines which contain `TEXT=` followed by *4* '-' delimited text segments.

Using GNU sed (treating "TEXT" and "yahoo" as constant)

```
sed -re 's/^(TEXT=[^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^-]+)-(yahoo)$/\1\2\3\4/'
```

Or, using GNU sed (treating all text after "=" as vairable)

```
sed -re 's/^(TEXT=[^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^-]+)$/\1\2\3\4/'
```

Or, for posix portability (treating all text after "=" as vairable):

```
sed 's/^\(TEXT=[^-][^-]*\)-\([^-][^-]*\)-\([^-][^-]*\)-\([^-][^-]*\)$/\1\2\3\4/'
```

Answer (score 6):

Here you go:

```
echo "TEXT=abcdef-lalala-someText-yahoo" | sed 's/-//g'
TEXT=abcdeflalalasomeTextyahoo
```

Comment: `sed -i 's/-//g' filename` is what would actually change it in the file, it would remove EVERY `-` in the file though, which might not be what you want.

Comment: Even though that works, I was thinking in little more sophisticated way to di it, for instance: sed -i 's/TEXT=......-......-........-...../wayToTellSedToLeaveOriginal6CharsWayToTellSedToLeaveOriginalSecond6CharsAndSoOn"7g' filename

Answer (score 1):

Here it is my two cents... You can add the match (TEXT=) before the substitute command... Just like this:

```
sed '/TEXT=/s/-//g'
```

The results will be:

```
echo "TEXT=abcdef-lalala-someText-yahoo" | sed '/TEXT=/s/-//g'
TEXT=abcdeflalalasomeTextyahoo
```

The substitute command will only be executed when match the first clause, in this case, match "TEXT=". I think that the command will be simpler and more elegant.